# Easiest way to find a value in one of three columns?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, heroku, twilio

I am using twilio to provide audio conference functionality in my rails app. When I call my conference number, twilio passes on a couple of values - including 'From' which contains the caller's phone number in international format.

I have a profile for every user in my system and in my controller I am querying the profile to provide a personalised welcome message. Every profile contains between 0 and 3 numbers (primary, secondary and cellphone) and I need to check the caller's ID against those three fields in all profiles.

When I use the console on my dev machine, the following code finds the correct profile:

```
Profile.find_by('+44000000000')
```

When I upload to heroku, I use following code instead:

```
name = Profile.find_by(params['From']) || 'there'
```

Which causes an error in my app:

```
2014-04-03T19:20:22.801284+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type bigint
2014-04-03T19:20:22.801284+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles"  WHERE (+4400000000) ...
```

Any suggestion how that could be solved?

Thanks!

---

Additional information:

I think my problem is that I don't know how to query either the whole profile or three columns at once. Right now the code:

```
name = Profile.find_by(params['From'])
```

is not correct (params['From'] contains a phone number) because I am not telling rails to query the columns primary phone number, secondary phone number and cellphone. Neither am I querying the whole profile which would also be an option.

So the question basically is:

How can I change this code:

```
Profile.find_by(params['From'])
```

so that it queries either all fields in all profiles or just the three columns with phone numbers which each profile contains?

Is there something like `Profile.where(:primary_number).or.where(:secondary_number)or.where(:cellphone) => params['From']`

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with twilio and not sure if this helps but **find** and **find_by_attribute_name** accepts array of values as options:

```
name = Profile.find_by([params['From'], 'there'] )
```

suppose `params['From']` was *here* , This should generate:

```
 SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` WHERE `profiles`.`attribute` IN ('here', 'there')
```

## Or:

If you are trying to build dynamic matcher at run time , which is called **[Meta-programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaprogramming)** , you can try this code:

name = eval("Profile.find_by_#{params['From']) || 'there'}(#rest of query params here) ")

## Update

First of all, i think you are not using `find_by` correctly!! the correct syntax is:

```
Model.find_by(attribute_name: value)
#e.g
Profile.find_by(phone_number: '0123456')
```

Which will call `where` and retrive one record, but passing a value will generate a condition that always passes, for example:

```
Model.find_by('wrong_condition')
#will generate SQL like:
SELECT `models`.* FROM `models` WHERE ('wrong_condition') LIMIT 1
#which will return the first record in the model since there is no valid condition here
```

Why don't you try:

```
Profile.where('primary_number = ? OR secondary_number = ? OR cellphone = ?', params['From'], params['From'], params['From'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I don't think that would solve the problem. I have added some additional information in the original post, maybe that helps?

Comment: @ThomasKuhlmann plz put the value expected at `params['From']` ?

Comment: params['From'] contains a phone number => +4400000000. And your last suggestion looks like it's doing the job - is there no simpler way though instead of repeating params["from'] three times?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your query like:

```
Profile.where("primary_number = ? or secondary_number = ? or cellphone = ?", params['From'])
```

Just double check the syntax, but that should do it.

Comment: I tried this one and it seems that I do need to provide the variable three times as suggested by Nimir. Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Oh, that was my bad I'm sorry. You can actually provide named variables in there instead of ? then you would only need to assign it one time.